# First positive root

Tags: equation-solving, polynomials

Simple question but problem with `NSolve`.

I need help how to extract first positive root?
For example:

```
 eq = -70.5 + 450.33 x^2 - 25 x^4;
 NSolve[ eq == 0, x]
```

If I have an equation `eq` that I am not sure of polynomial order and I need to define
all positive roots `x[1], ..., x[2]`.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The most straightforward way would be `FindRoot[ eq, {x, 0}]` but since this specific polynomial `eq` has a singular Jacobian at `x == 0` (evaluate e.g. `Reduce[ D[ eq, x] == 0, x]`) one would rather use `FindRoot[ eq, {x, x0}]` for small `x0 > 0`. The argument `x0` depends on a case by case basis, but for the problem at hand an appropriate value might be `0 < x0 <= 2.4`,  e.g. :

```
FindRoot[ eq, {x, 0.5}]
```

> ```
> {x -> 0.397412}
> ```

More general considerations must include **huge order polynomials**, which might have many real roots. So finding every root may be very inefficient. In such cases there is a handy function `RootInterval` which can be much more efficient than any `NSolve` approach and especially handy when using it together with `FindRoot`.

```
First @ RootIntervals[eq]
```

> ```
> {{-(273/64), -(263/64)}, {-(33/64), -(23/64)}, {47/128, 57/128}, {263/64, 273/64}}
> ```

It shows where one can find the first positive root , i.e. in this interval : `{47/128, 57/128}`. To choose only intervals where positive roots may be found we use e.g. :

```
intervals = First @ RootIntervals[eq] ~ DeleteCases ~ {_, _?Negative}
```

> ```
> {{47/128, 57/128}, {263/64, 273/64}}
> ```

Then we use it for finding roots numerically with [`Brent's method`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/UnconstrainedOptimizationBrentsMethod.html) -- the most powerful algorithm available for `FindRoot` :

```
roots = FindRoot[ eq, {x, #[[1]], #[[2]]}, Method -> "Brent"][[All, 2]]& /@ intervals //
        Flatten
```

> ```
> {0.397412, 4.22555}
> ```

The last step is standard :

```
Min @ roots
```

> ```
> 0.397412
> ```

The first root might be negative therefore we could use e.g. :

```
RankedMin[roots, #]& /@ {1, 2}
```

Now for the sake of completeness we demonstrate small `intervals` and `roots` on the plot of the polynomial over the positive reals :

```
Plot[ eq, {x, -4.5, 4.5}, PlotStyle -> Thick, AspectRatio -> 1/3, Epilog -> {
          Darker @ Red, Thickness[0.005], Line[{{#1, 0}, {#2, 0}}]& @@@ intervals,
          Green, PointSize[0.007], Point[{#, 0}] & /@ roots } ]
```

[image]

the same plot  in pieces :

```
GraphicsRow[ 
    Plot[   eq, {x, #1 - 0.3, #2 + 0.3}, PlotStyle -> Thickness[0.01], Epilog -> {
                 Red, Thickness[0.011], Line[{{#1, 0}, {#2, 0}}] & @@@ intervals, 
                 Green, PointSize[0.015], Point[{#, 0}] & /@ roots}] & @@@ intervals ]
```

[image]

Comment: Congrats! Fully answer.

Comment: @Artes: How can you generalize your `Code` given above to a system of nonlinear equations? I am struggling to find real solutions to the NL system. Can you give me an example, for example, for a system of 5 nonlinear (NL) equations? and find the equilibrium limited to only real values.

Comment: @TugrulTemel `eq==0` is a nonlinear equation, to solve a system you should use something like `FindRoot[{eq1==0,...,eq5==0},{{x1,y0},...,{x5,y5}}]` possibly with an appropriate method.  For a specific problem you should better ask another question. Sometimes you can get solutions with `Solve` or `NSolve` with domain specification, eg. `NSolve[{eq1==0,...eq5==0},{x1,...,x5},Reals]`.

Comment: @Artes: Thank you very much. I cannot figure out why `NSolve` is very slow for a system of 30 equations (mixed: linear and nonlinear). Regards.

Comment: @TugrulTemel  It is not surprising, that solving systems of 30 equations is very slow. In such a case more reasonable is to exploit  `FindRoot`.

Answer (score 14):

```
    eq = -70.5 + 450.33 x^2 - 25 x^4;
    roots = x /. NSolve[eq == 0, x]
    Min@Select[roots, Positive]
0.397412
```

Comment: yes, but how to extract second, third ... separately?

Comment: @Pipe you can use `Sort` instead of `Min` to get the ordered positive roots

Comment: @Nasser it is working but how to extract just second for example

Comment: @Nasser Thank you very much, it is clear now

Comment: @Pipe: Had you asked for how to extract the 2nd or 3rd, etc., I would have indeed have used `Sort` instead of `Min`. But you asked just for the 1st!

Answer (score 5):

Well, if you wanted to give `NSolve` your conditions directly, you can do

```
NSolve[-70.5 + 450.33 x^2 - 25 x^4 == 0 && x > 0, x]
```

And then if you want, you can pick the `Min` solution.