# Multiple ranges in one plot

Tags: plotting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [1 Plot, 2 Scale/Axis](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/627/1-plot-2-scale-axis)
>   [Generating a broken or snipped axis in ListPlot](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/8241/generating-a-broken-or-snipped-axis-in-listplot)

I have data in several ranges which I, when I plot together, is not very useful. I was thinking about removing the regions where no data exist (see data.png), e.g. shrink the plot scale in those regions.

In other words, specifying multiple ranges for the PlotRange option:

PlotRange-> {{xrange1,xrange2, xrange3},yrange}

How would I go about this?

[image]

Comment: Can you use log-type plots ? In general, if you provide the code and the data you used you'll get greater attention.

Comment: No, Log-Linear plot does not improve the situation much.

Comment: it seems making 3 plots next to each other (using `GraphicsRow`) would do the trick nicely?

Comment: @n3rd At the end of this post http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/16574/first-positive-root/16579#16579 there is an example how to do it.

Comment: if you paste `howto/GeneratePlotsWithTwoVerticalScales` into the help browser you'll find some code to do that. Also [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/627/16)  it's done for data (rather than functions).

Comment: Duplicate: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/8241/121 -- I will close this question soon unless others disagree.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I think it's a tossup whether it's a duplicate to the question you said or to [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/627/16), depending on the presentation n3rd wants