# Switching parameter lines on/off in a 3D parametric plot

Tags: plotting, parametric-functions

In a classroom demonstration for

```
ParametricPlot3D [{f[u, v], g[u, v], h[u, v]}, {u, ... }, {v, ... }]
```

I want to show

- u lines only without v,
- v lines only without u,
- no lines, only surface,
- no surface, only u, v lines.

How can it be done?

Comment: Similar: [How to dynamically toggle curves on/off in a crowded Plot?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/20112), [Highlight selected curve on the plot](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/35449)

Comment: Let us say we pick up options for two separate images  out of the full Manipulate set: GrU= {uMesh True,uMesh=18, v Mesh False,Surface, Boxed -> False} and GrV= {vMesh True, vMesh=10,u Mesh False,WireFrame, Boxed-> True} and combine them in:
Show[GrU,GrV].

How  it be done?   *)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
Manipulate[
 ParametricPlot3D[
  {Cos[u], Sin[u] + Cos[v], Sin[v]},
  {u, 0, 2 \[Pi]},
  {v, -\[Pi], \[Pi]},
  Mesh -> {If[uMeshOn, uMesh, 0],
    If[vMeshOn, vMesh, 0]},
  Boxed -> boxed,
  Axes -> boxed,
  PlotStyle -> pltStyle],
 Row[{
   Control[
    {{uMesh, 15, "u Mesh"}, 0, 36, 1,
     Appearance -> "Labeled",
     ImageSize -> Small}],
   Spacer[5],
   Control[
    {{vMesh, 15, "v Mesh"}, 0, 36, 1,
     Appearance -> "Labeled",
     ImageSize -> Small}]}],
 Row[{Control[
    {{uMeshOn, True, "u Mesh"},
     {True, False}}],
   Spacer[20],
   Control[
    {{vMeshOn, True, "v Mesh"},
     {True, False}}],
   Spacer[20],
   Control[
    {{pltStyle, Automatic, "Plot Style"},
     {Automatic -> "Surface",
      FaceForm[] -> "Wire Frame"}}],
   Spacer[20],
   Control[
    {{boxed, True, "Boxed"},
     {True, False}}]}]]
```

[image]

Comment: A particularly appropriate choice of surface, too! +1

Comment: Wondrously beautiful this Bob,can ask for nothing more!