# How to discern the different curves?

Tags: plotting

When we plot many curves, due to repeated colors it becomes difficult to discern that which curve belongs to which equation.

For instance,

```
Plot[{n!, n^n, Exp[n], Log[n], n^100, 10^n}, {n, 0, 2},   PlotLegends
 -> "Expressions"]
```

If am wondering whether there is a way to differentiate the different curves by clicking on the equation and highlighting the respective curve?

thanks

Comment: Related: [20112](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/20112/how-to-dynamically-toggle-curves-on-off-in-a-crowded-plot), [35449](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/35449/highlight-selected-curve-on-the-plot)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
Plot[Tooltip[{n!, n^n, Exp[n], Log[n], n^100, 10^n}], {n, 0, 2}]
```

Now when you hover over the plot, the tooltip (the little popup window) tells which curve the mouse is pointing at.

Answer (score 3):

You can also specify your own plot styles and for functions with large ranges consider `LogPlot`, e.g.

```
LogPlot[{n!, n^n, Exp[n], Log[n], n^100, 10^n}, {n, 0, 2}, 
 PlotStyle -> {{Red, Dashing[{0.03, 0.03}]}, Green, Blue, 
   Orange, {Purple, Dashing[{0.03, 0.03}]}, Black}, 
 PlotLegends -> "Expressions"]
```

[image]