# FindRoot in range

Tags: equation-solving

I am trying to find all roots in a range, using

```
y /. FindRoot[Sin[y] == 0, {y, #}] & /@ Range[7]
```

which gives

```
{0., 3.14159, 3.14159, 3.14159, 9.42478, 6.28319, 6.28319}
```

but I would like to get

```
{0., 3.14159, 6.28319}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Reduce can often find all roots in an interval.  Have you tried it? http://blog.wolfram.com/2008/12/18/mathematica-7-johannes-kepler-and-transcendental-roots/

Comment: If for some reasons you want to work with `FindRoot` (e.g. because it is much faster for a large class of transcendental equations) you may exploit the technique using `RootIntervals` as in this answer [First positive root](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/16574/first-positive-root/16579#16579) and instead of `Sin[x]` use the first terms of its Taylor series e.g. `N@First@RootIntervals[Series[Sin[x], {x, 0, 15}] // Normal]`. This information is all you may need to work out the solution.

Comment: @Szabolcs - many thanks - solved with `Reduce` as you suggested :)

Comment: @Artes - many thanks - great links - ended up using `Reduce` - by looking at your answer [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/17127/what-is-the-difference-between-reduce-and-solve) :)

Comment: @martin I'm glad it worked. It doesn't always work and it's *much* slower than FindRoot-based solutions.

Comment: @martin I think you can answer your question using `FindRoot` as well even though I wouldn't use it here (`Solve[Sin[x] == 0 && 0 <= x <= 2 Pi, x]` works too ). For transcendental equations involving trigonometric functions as algebraic variables `Reduce` and `Solve` will work in general (look e.g. here [How to get intersection values from a parametric graph?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/33947/how-to-get-intersection-values-from-a-parametric-graph/33952#33952) for a simple exception of `Solve`).

Comment: You could also use `NSolve[Sin[x] == 0 && 0 <= x <= 7, x]` which gives the result `{{x -> 0.}, {x -> 3.14159}, {x -> 6.28319}}`.

Comment: You could also use `y /. FindRoot[Sin[y] == 0, {y, #}] & /@ Range[7] // Union`