# how to find numerical zeros of $f(z)$ in a compact complex domain

Tags: equation-solving

I encountered a function $f(z)$ with several zeros in a region $1<\Re(z)<2, 3<\Im(z)<4$. These zeros are visible in a three dimensional plot like

```
  Plot3D[-Log[Abs[f[x+ I y]]],{x,1,2},{y,3,4}]
```

Is there any method in *Mathematica* 7.0 or 9.0 that can find these numerical zeros automatically and completely?

EDIT:
A test function is:

```
f[t_] := Exp[-2Pi Cosh[2t]] (2 + Cosh[2t]) (1/2 - Cosh[t])
```

Another test function is:

```
g[t_] := Exp[-2Pi Cosh[2t]] (Pi - 2 Cosh[Pi t] + Sqrt[2] Cosh[2t] - Cosh[Pi t] Cosh[2t])
```

Comment: Try: `FindInstance[-Log[Abs[f[x+I y]]]==0&&1<x<2&&3<y<4&&Element[x,Reals]&&Element[y,Reals],{x,y},Complexes,100]`

Comment: It depends on the function `f`. Since you haven't provided it, your question cannot be reasonably answered, nevertheless if `Reduce[ f[z]==0&&1<Re[z]<2&&3<Im[z]<4,z]` cannot answer this question there one should use appropriately the `FindRoot` function, see e.g. this answer [First positive root](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/16574/first-positive-root/16579#16579) although `Method -> "Brent"` works for real valued functions.

Comment: @Tyilo. Your method of "FindInstant" worked fine for the test function I just added in the OP. But it did not work if I replace $f(z)$ by $g(z)=f(z)//N$.  It seemed to me that it can only solve the symbolic equations exactly.  The actual function I have does not have exact solutions. So I can only solve it nemerically.  Thanks-

Comment: Let f[t_] = Exp[-2*Pi*Cosh[2*t]]*(2 + Cosh[2*t])*(1/2 - Cosh[t]), then Reduce[f[t] == 0, t] gives Element[C[1], 
  Integers] && (t == -((I*Pi)/3) + 2*I*Pi*C[1] || 
   t == (I*Pi)/3 + 2*I*Pi*C[1] || 
   t == (1/2)*(-ArcCosh[-2] + 2*I*Pi*C[1]) || 
   t == (1/2)*(ArcCosh[-2] + 2*I*Pi*C[1])). I haven't checked if there are more roots than these.

Comment: @Dr.WolfgangHintze.  Thanks for the suggestions. Your method worked for f[t] in the example. I think that the most probable reason is that f[z] can be factored. If g[t_] := Exp[-2*Pi Cosh[2*t]]*(\[Pi] - 2 Cosh[\[Pi] t] + 
    Sqrt[2] Cosh[2 t] - Cosh[\[Pi] t] Cosh[2 t]), then "Reduce[g[t]==0,t]" command does not seems to work for me. Neither do "Reduce[N[g[t]]==0,t]".

Comment: This looks like a good time to use [`FindAllCrossings2D[]`](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/275): `FindAllCrossings2D[{Re[f[x + I y]] == 0, Im[f[x + I y]] == 0}, {x, 1, 2}, {y, 3, 4}]`

Answer (score 3):

If you can make the function look explicitly real e.g. using `ComplexExpand`, then `Reduce` might be able to do what you have in mind. Here is a simple example.

```
f[x_] := x^2 - 3 x + 14
Reduce[-Log[ComplexExpand[Abs[f[x + I y]]]] == 0 && 
  1 <= x <= 2 && 3 <= y <= 4, {x, y}]

(* Out[143]= (x == 1/94 (141 - 2 Sqrt[47]) && 
   y == Root[
     195 - 84 x + 37 x^2 - 6 x^3 + 
       x^4 + (-19 - 6 x + 2 x^2) #1^2 + #1^4 &, 3]) || (1/
     94 (141 - 2 Sqrt[47]) < x < 
    1/94 (141 + 2 Sqrt[47]) && (y == 
      Root[195 - 84 x + 37 x^2 - 6 x^3 + 
         x^4 + (-19 - 6 x + 2 x^2) #1^2 + #1^4 &, 3] || 
     y == Root[
       195 - 84 x + 37 x^2 - 6 x^3 + 
         x^4 + (-19 - 6 x + 2 x^2) #1^2 + #1^4 &, 4])) || (x == 
    1/94 (141 + 2 Sqrt[47]) && 
   y == Root[
     195 - 84 x + 37 x^2 - 6 x^3 + 
       x^4 + (-19 - 6 x + 2 x^2) #1^2 + #1^4 &, 3]) *)
```

Comment: The functions are:

Comment: I added a test function in OP. Your method does not seem to work.  If it worked for you, please replace $f(z)$ by $g(z)=f(z)//N$ and try to solve $g(z)$.  Thanks-

Answer (score 2):

Treating the problem purely numerically, one thing you can do is trace out lines in the complex plane, then use standard 1D root finding techniques:

For your example this simple approach works just fine seaching on lines of constant x:

```
 f[z_] := -N@Log[Abs[Exp[-2 Pi Cosh[2 z]] (2 + Cosh[2 z]) (1/2 - Cosh[2 z])]]
 zero[x_?NumericQ] := y /. First@FindRoot[ f[x + I y ], {y, 2, 3}]
 locus = First@Cases[ Plot[ zero[x], {x, 1, 2}] , Line[x_] :> x , Infinity];
 Show[{
  Plot3D[f[x + I y], {x, 1, 2}, {y, 2, 3}, PlotRange -> {-120, 160}],
  Graphics3D[{Thick, Red, Line[Append[#, 0] & /@ locus], 
    Green, Polygon[ { {1,2,0} , {2,2,0} , {2,3,0}, {1,3,0}}]}]}]
```

[image]

This obviously depends not only on the function being smooth, but on the chance of your choice of search curves hitting your roots.  I suspect the fully general problem is intractable.

Incidentally, for this example `FindRoot` can directly find one point:

```
 FindRoot[ { f[x + I y ], 0}, {x, 1, 2}, {y, 2, 3}]
```

> {x -> 0.171946, y -> 2.37038}

(note we have to trick it into thinking there are two equations.. )