# How to obtain numerical solutions of a two-variable equation?

Tags: equation-solving, calculus-and-analysis, functions, numerics, numerical-value

I have a two-variable function:

```
f[x_, y_] := (4 y^2 - 6) (Cos[y π] Cos[x] - Cos[2 y π] Sin[x])
```

How can I find all the numerical solutions for $x$ and $y$ such that $f(x,y)=0$?
The domains are $0<x<\pi$ and $0<y<5$.

More precisely, I want to ask Mathematica to consider $x$ with the step $\frac{\pi }{5}$ and provide the values of $y$ for them.

Comment: Please have a look at `FindRoot`.

Comment: @b.gates.you.know.what  I want to obtain a list of solutions, not for a specific value!

Comment: Do you want the blue curves in @Artes' answer or really the red dots?  That is, is the stepping of `x` by $\pi/5$ just for convenience or is it essential to what you want?

Comment: @Chris K The function I used is just an example of what I wanted to know.  Stepping could be different. I wanted to know a command in Mathematica that I can use to obtain numerical solutions of a two-variable function.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There are infinitely many (continuum) solutions and basically one cannot list them all e.g. because of the [Cantor theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor%27s_theorem). This is the reason why  numerical approach is unsatisfactory. However we can make use of `FindRoot` to find a finite numerical subset of the solution space.

**Numerical solutions**

First we set up a net of values of `x` and starting point of `y` (we denote them by `k` in `Table`)

```
nsol = Flatten[ Table[{x, y}/.FindRoot[(4y^2 - 6)(Cos[π y]Cos[x] - Cos[2π y] Sin[x]) == 0,
                                          {y, k}], 
                       {x, π/5, 4 π/5, π/5}, {k, 1/3, 14/3, 1/3}], 
                1] // DeleteDuplicates;

Show[ ContourPlot[(4 y^2 - 6) (Cos[π y] Cos[x] - Cos[2π y] Sin[x]) == 0,
                  {x, -π/2, 2π}, {y, -0.1, 5.1}, 
                  PlotPoints -> 50, MaxRecursion -> 3, 
                  Epilog -> {Red, PointSize[0.023], Point[nsol]}], 
      RegionPlot[ Not[0 < x < π && 0 < y < 5], {x, -π/2, 2π}, {y, -0.1, 5.1}]]
```

[image]

Numerical solutions are contained in `nsol`, we write only a few and hiding `38` of them:

```
Short[N @ nsol, 3]
```

> ```
> {{0.628319, -0.645834}, {0.628319, 0.645834}, <<38>>, {2.51327, 4.35417},
>  {2.51327, 5.64583}}
> ```

One can see that the first point in `nsol` doesn't belong to the domain of our interest. We can get rid of such points setting a different net of starting points in `FindRoot` or using another tools of the system, however this approach might be more involved for more sophisticated transcendental equations. An example of more detailed discussion how to deal with `FindRoot` can be found at e.g. [First positive root](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/16574/first-positive-root/16579#16579).

**Exact (symbolic) solution**

More interesting is finding an exact descripton of the blue curves which represent  symbolic solutions. The form of our equation $f(x,y)=0$ can be factorized into two algebraic expressions and the roots of the original equation is the set-theoretic sum of  solutions of two equations: `4 y^2 - 6 == 0` and `(Cos[π y] Cos[x] - Cos[2π y] Sin[x]) == 0`.

The straight line is the solution of this equation (for x in the range `0 < x < π`)

```
Solve[(4 y^2 - 6) == 0 && 0 < y < 5, y]
```

> ```
>  {{y -> Sqrt[3/2]}}
> ```

While another equation gives us those periodic curves, moreover it appears that one can solve equation for `x` obtaining it as a function of `y`.

```
Reduce[(Cos[π y] Cos[x] - Cos[2π y] Sin[x]) == 0 && 0 < x < π, x, Reals]
```

> ```
>   (Cos[π y] != 0 && Cos[π y] != 0 && 
> x == 2 ArcTan[ Sec[π y] (-Cos[2π y] + Cos[π y] Sqrt[(Cos[π y]^2 + 
>          Cos[2 π y]^2) Sec[π y]^2])]) ||
> ((-π + x)/(2 π) \[NotElement] Integers && Cos[π y] == 0 && 
>  Cos[2 π y] == 0 && 0 < x < π)
> ```

This expression could be further simplified however the main point is the parametrization of curves with

```
FullSimplify[ x == 2 ArcTan[ Sec[π y] (-Cos[2π y] + Cos[π y] Sqrt[(Cos[π y]^2       
                             + Cos[2π y]^2) Sec[π y]^2])], 
              0 < x < π && 0 < y < 5] // TraditionalForm
```

[image]

For some reasons the standard approach with `Reduce` on the original equation takes a long time returning quite an involved expression even though the equation is not hard to solve when we deal with different factors of the original function. Finially we plot the graph of the above symbolic solutions with red points denoting numerical ones, yet another time we exploit `ContourPlot`

```
Show[
  ContourPlot[{x == -2ArcTan[ Cos[2π y]Sec[π y] - Sqrt[1 + Cos[2π y]^2 Sec[π y]^2]], 
               y == Sqrt[3/2]}, {x, -π/2, 2π}, {y, -0.3, 5.3}, 
              PlotPoints -> 50, MaxRecursion -> 3, 
              ContourStyle -> {{Thick, Darker@Cyan}, Thick, Magenta}, 
              Epilog -> {Red, PointSize[0.016], Point[nsol]}], 
  RegionPlot[ Not[0 < x < π && 0 < y < 5], {x, -π/2, 2π}, {y, -0.3, 5.3}]]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But I want to know which command I can use to obtain numerical data for general types of functions. Do you have any idea?

Comment: @Baran `FindRoot` is the function you are looking for. I've presented how to use it, red points on the graph are found with `FindRoot`. However those blue curves can be found with a symbolic tool `Reduce`. Just evaluate `nsol` from my answer to find out numerical solutions.

Comment: @Baran Could you explain what did you expect by "numerical solutions", and why `FindRoot` did not satisfied your expectation? I'm just curious about it.

Comment: Now, I am satisfied with FindRoot and NSolve. thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Reduce also seems to work on the original f, though the answer it gives is somewhat long and involves a collection of Tan and ArcTan.

```
f[x_, y_] := (4 y^2 - 6) (Cos[y \[Pi]] Cos[x] - Cos[2 y \[Pi]] Sin[x]);
Reduce[f[x, y] == 0, {x, y}]
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. My question is: is there a command to obtain numerical solutions for these types of two-variable function s?

Comment: It seems to me that Reduce gives an exact and explicit set of solutions. It's complicated, but so is your function.