# Numerical solution of the inverse contour plot

Tags: equation-solving, numerics, numerical-value, inverse

I have a function $f(u,v)$ on some domain of $(u,v)$ and would like to find (numerically) the set of couples* $(u_0,v_0)$ s.t. $f(u_0,v_0)=0$, for instance (just and example to illustrate, in practice I will use arbitrary non analytical functions)

```
  ContourPlot[BesselJ[3, Sin[u^2 - v]] == 0, {u, -1, 1}, {v, -1, 1}]
```

[image]

`FindRoot` does not work immediately because it needs two equations. Any easy implementation for this problem ?

*"the set of couples" has naturally infinite elements, so I would expect a set of finitely countable elements with adjustable density.

Comment: Try `ContourPlot[...,PlotPoints->100]`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem appears to be solvable with an exact approach, e.g.

```
Reduce[ BesselJ[3, Sin[u^2 - v]] == 0 && 
        -1 <= u <= 1 && -1 <= v <= 1, {u, v}]
```

> ```
>   -1 <= u <= 1 && v == u^2
> ```

Nevertheless numerically one can solve it this way:

```
sol[u_] = v /. NSolve[ BesselJ[3, Sin[u^2 - v]] == 0 &&
                      -1 <= u <= 1 && -1 <= v <= 1, {u, v}] //First//Quiet;
```

or with `FindRoot`  (this is more powerful when we deal with special functions):

```
ns[u_] := v /. FindRoot[BesselJ[3, Sin[u^2 - v]] == 0, {v, 0}]

{sol[0.37], ns[0.37]}
```

> ```
>  {0.1369, 0.1369}
> ```

In case of a more involved equations we could  modify  starting point in `FindRoot` or exploit various options e.g. [First positive root](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/16574/first-positive-root/16579#16579).

```
Plot[{sol[u], ns[u]}, {u, -1, 1}, PlotStyle -> {Blue, Dashed}]
```

[image]

If a set of pairs $(u,v)$ is needed, let's go a directly taking $100$ random arguments:

```
dmn = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, 100];
SetAttributes[ns, Listable]
pairs = Transpose[{dmn, ns[dmn]}];
ListPlot[Transpose[{dmn, ns[dmn]}]]
```

Answer (score 5):

```
sol = FindInstance[{BesselJ[3, Sin[u^2 - v]] == 0, -1 <= u <= 1, -1 <=
      v <= 1}, {u, v}, 1000];
ListPlot[{u, v} /. sol]
```

[image]

**Replay to comment**

```
Clear[sol, pts]; sol = 
 FindInstance[{BesselJ[3, Sin[u^2 - v]] == 0, -1 <= u <= 1, -1 <= v <=
     1}, {u, v}, 1000];
pts = SortBy[{u, v} /. sol, First];
Plot[Interpolation[pts][x], {x, -1, 1}]
```

Comment: I'm using an interpolation function and for some reason it's not working (the list plot returns empty).

Comment: @DanielCastro  See the updated.

Answer (score 2):

Take the point pairs from `ContourPlot`

```
pic = ContourPlot[BesselJ[3, Sin[u^2 - v]] == 0,{u, -1, 1}, {v, -1, 1}]
uvi= pic[[1]][[1, 1]];

Show[pic, ListPlot[uvi, PlotStyle -> Red]]
```

[image]

If necessary you might take these values as starting point for further improvement with `FindRoot`

```
uviI = Map[{#[[1]], v} /.FindRoot[BesselJ[3, Sin[#[[1]]^2 - v]] ==0, {v, #[[2]]}] &, uvi];

Show[pic,ListPlot[{uvi, uviI, uviI}, PlotStyle ->{Red, Blue, Cyan}, Joined -> {False, False, True}]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

```
Clear["Global`*"]
```

To use [`FindRoot`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindRoot.html) directly,

```
vSol[u_?NumericQ, est_ : 1/2] :=
 v /. FindRoot[BesselJ[3, Sin[u^2 - v]] == 0, {v, est}]

Plot[vSol[u], {u, -1, 1},
 Frame -> True,
 FrameLabel -> (Style[#, 14, Bold] & /@ {u, v})]
```

[image]

Change the initial estimate of the root to get a different branch.

```
Plot[vSol[u, 1/2 - Pi], {u, -1, 1},
 Frame -> True,
 FrameLabel -> (Style[#, 14, Bold] & /@ {u, v})]
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Regard v as function of u, v[u], and differentiate function f[u,v[u]] to be zero with respect to u and generate interpolating function for v[u] with NDSolve.

Here shown for two branches.

```
f[u_, v_] = BesselJ[3, Sin[u^2 - v]];
cp = ContourPlot[f[u, v] == 0, {u, -1, 1}, {v, -3.5, 1}];

fi1 = First@
  FindInstance[f[u, v] == 0 && -1 < u < 1 && -1 < v < 1, {u, v}]
fi2 = First@
  FindInstance[f[u, v] == 0 && -1 < u < 1 && -3 < v < -2, {u, v}]

vsol1 = v /. 
   First@NDSolve[{D[f[u, v[u]], u] == 0, v[u /. fi1] == (v /. fi1)}, 
     v, {u, -1, 1}];
vsol2 = v /. 
   First@NDSolve[{D[f[u, v[u]], u] == 0, v[u /. fi2] == (v /. fi2)}, 
     v, {u, -1, 1}];

pl = Plot[{vsol1[u], vsol2[u]}, {u, -1, 1}, PlotStyle -> {Red, Green}];
Show[cp, pl, GridLines -> Automatic, Frame -> True]
```

[image]